# How to create regular Expression in Python for a specific type of Alpha numeric word

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for suggestions to create a regular expression based search in Python. I have got following type of string values in a server log file,

2017-03-18 13:24:05,791 INFO  [STDOUT]  SUB Request Status :Resubmitted INBIOS_ABZ824
2017-03-12 13:24:05,796 INFO  [STDOUT] SUB Submit Status :Resubmitted INDROS_MSR656
2017-04-12 13:24:05,991 INFO  [STDOUT]  SUB Request Status :Resubmitted INHP_GSN848

and I need to search the log and extract the values like following,

2017-03-18 13:24:05,791     INBIOS_ABZ824
2017-03-12 13:24:05,796     INDROS_MSR656
2017-04-12 13:24:05,991     INHP_GSN848

I am using the following code, but its extracting the complete line where the strings like these are present (INBIOS_ABZ824). How can I extract only the specified values from the log as above, Please share your thoughts.

```
import os
import re

# Regex used to match relevant loglines (in this case)

line_regex = re.compile(r"[A-Z]+IOS_[A-Z]+[0-9]+", re.IGNORECASE)


# Output file, where the matched loglines will be copied to
output_filename = os.path.normpath("output.log")
# Overwrites the file, ensure we're starting out with a blank file
with open(output_filename, "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write("")

# Open output file in 'append' mode
with open(output_filename, "a") as out_file:
    # Open input file in 'read' mode
    with open("ServerError.txt", "r") as in_file:
        # Loop over each log line
        for line in in_file:
            # If log line matches our regex, print to console, and output file
            if (line_regex.search(line)):
                print(line)
                out_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go, finally got the perfect answer. Which will only extract the required strings as well as eliminate the other values which are associated with the patter.

Here I am refining the search results with another re.match() call before its finally sent to outfile.

```
import os
import re

# Regex used to match relevant loglines (in this case, a specific IP address)
line_regex = re.compile(r"error", re.IGNORECASE)

line_regex = re.compile(r"[A-Z]+OS_[A-Z]+[0-9]+", re.IGNORECASE)


# Output file, where the matched loglines will be copied to
output_filename = os.path.normpath("output.log")
# Overwrites the file, ensure we're starting out with a blank file
with open(output_filename, "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write("")

# Open output file in 'append' mode
with open(output_filename, "a") as out_file:
    # Open input file in 'read' mode
    with open("ServerError.txt", "r") as in_file:
        # Loop over each log line
        for line in in_file:
            # If log line matches our regex, print to console, and output file
            if (line_regex.search(line)):

                # Get index of last space
                last_ndx = line.rfind(' ')
                # line[:23]: The time stamp (first 23 characters)
                # line[last_ndx:]: Last space and following characters
                # using match object to eliminate other strings which are associated with the pattern ,
                # need the string from which the request ID is in the last index
                matchObj = re.match(line_regex, line[last_ndx+1:])
                #print(matchObj)
                #check if matchobj is not null
                if matchObj:
                    print(line[:23] + line[last_ndx:])
                    out_file.write(line[:23] + line[last_ndx:])
```

Answer (score 1):

A single regexp should do.  The common thread seems to be all-uppercase alpha, starting with something followed by `TEC_`, more alpha and a number, so...

> `[A-Z]+TEC_[A-Z]+[0-9]+`

See https://regexr.com/3qveu for a test.

Answer (score 1):

You could match one or more uppercase characters `[A-Z]+`, an underscore `_` and then zero or more `[A-Z]*` times an uppercase character followed by one or more digits `[0-9]+`.

Use might use a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` so it is not part of a longer match.

`\b[A-Z]+_[A-Z]*[0-9]+\b`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C4CBdb/1)